# Import bootstrap error: Unexpected token, test-utils, working in one test but not another

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm new to unit testing with jest in vue.

I have added the plugin unit test from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest

It have created a test folder with another folder called unit where I have placed 2 files: Footer.spec.js and Main.spec.js. It also created a jest.config.js file.

Footer.spec.js

```
import '../../src/plugins/fontawesome'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Footer from '../../src/components/Footer/Footer.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('Footer', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(BootstrapVue)
  const wrapper = mount(Footer, {localVue})

  it('has a FooterPhoneNumber', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('some HTML')
  })

  it('has a FooterEmail', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('some HTML')
  })
})
```

Main.spec.js

```
import '../../src/plugins/fontawesome'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Main from '../../src/components/Main.vue'
import BootstrapVueMain from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { createLocalVueMain } from '@vue/test-utils'

describe('Main', () => {
  const localVueMain = createLocalVueMain()
  localVueMain.use(BootstrapVueMain)
  const wrapper = mount(Main, {localVueMain})

  it('the modal for browser not compatible', () => {
    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('some HTML')
  })
})
```

From the jest.config.js

```
 transformIgnorePatterns: [
   '/node_modules/(?!(bootstrap|bootstrap-vue)/)',
   '/node_modules/',
 ],
```

I'm getting an error because of 2 imports:

```
     import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
     | ^
  18 | import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

The Footer.spec.js pass the test but the Main.spec.js dosen't.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Main.spec.js` you are importing and using `createLocalVueMain()`, instead of `createLocalVue()`. Because of that, BootstrapVue is not registered to localVue instance - because it was not created.